# Transform masked area in sculpting mode

Tags: modeling, transforms, sculpting

I'm trying to rotate a masked area in sculpting mode, but the pivot is right at the center of the world(scene). Is there a way to move the pivot in sculpting mode? What I'm trying to do is to move the pivot to the center of the unmasked area.

I've been trying to find info on this in the manuals and watching Pablo's twitter videos but I still can't find the solution.

Comment: In other areas of Blender you can move the 3D Cursor and choose Transform Pivot point 3D Cursor. to enable choose rotation mode around the 3D Cursor.  (Shift Context Click approximately to move 3D Cursor)  .  Change the setting on the tool bar to use the 3D Cursor as center or rotation.  Suggestion try it with a simple mesh to see this.

Comment: Loosely related and there is a pic of the Transform Pivot https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43826/how-to-efficiently-merge-geometry-and-get-rid-of-internal-shapes-etc/43832#43832

Comment: Just to be clear there is a 3D Cursor and the different ..... Origin of a Mesh. And various ways to move the 3D Cursor.  (Perhaps Shift S)

Answer (score 2):

You find an easy way to move the pivot to the center of the unmasked part
at the menu item
*Sculpt* (right next to *Sculpt Mode* and *View*) > *Set Pivot* > *Pivot to Unmasked*.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done is go *Sculpt -> Set Pivot -> Pivot to Surface Under Cursor* and hotkey it: the pivot will be set to wherever your cursor is on the mesh during the button press. it works well for re-sizing / rotating arms and legs